# Neo4j cypher to filter date and hour ranges doesn't give required results

Tags: python, neo4j

I am a bit new to neo4j and struggling to construct a proper cypher query for the following use case: My network has source ---> destination relations where ---> is a GoesTo label with property date and hour (0-23).
Now i wish to construct a query that fetches all the nodes between 2 dates and 2 hours. I am using the query shared below but it doesn't give correct results.

```
dates = [20150501,20150502]
#date1=20150501
#date2=20150502
hour1 = 13 # starting hour for date1
hour2 = 12 # ending hour for date2
hours = [hour1,hour2]
q9a = """
MATCH (c:Gate)-[r:GoesTo]->(d:Gate) WHERE (r.date >= {date1} AND r.hour >= {houra}) AND (r.date <={date2}  AND r.hour <= {hourb})
            RETURN c.name AS FromGate, d.name AS ToGate, sum(r.weight) 
            AS WDegree ORDER BY WDegree DESC
"""
result = graph.cypher.execute(q9a, date1=dates[0],date2=dates[1], houra=hours[0], hourb=hours[1])
```

this query returns empty result as i understand that i am using a common 'r' for r.hour. Any tips please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving it using unix time. I converted timestamps to unix time and added unixtime as property to each edge and then the query was good to go.

Comment: Which object in python did you use for getting unixtime?